# C++: When should I use structs instead of classes and where are the speed differences?

Tags: c++, oop, struct

- When should I use a `struct` instead of a class? I'm currently using classes for everything from OpenGL texture wrappers to bitmap fonts.
- Is a class that I use just like a `struct` (no making usage of inheritance, polymorphism, etc.) still slower than a `struct`?

Comment: There are a number of other very similar questions already on SO.

Comment: And none of them concerns efficiency of either, do they, now?

Comment: @Armen: no, they just say *they are exactly the same*. Then it is left as an exercise for the reader to make the leap of deduction that *if they are exactly the same*, then *they are probably equally efficient too*.

Comment: @jalf: Interesting form of deduction. :) If they are exactly the same, then the performance *is* exactly the same.

Answer (score 41):

Structs and classes in C++ as you may know ***differ solely by their default access level*** (and default accessibility of their bases: public for struct, private for class).

Some developers, including myself prefer to use structs for [POD-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special), that is, with C-style structs, with no virtual functions, bases etc. Structs should not have behavior - they are just a comglomerate of data put into one object.

But that is naturally a matter of style, and obviously neither is slower

Comment: For clarification: a "POD type" means "plain old data", and refers to a struct or class that is basically the same as a C struct in terms of performance.  See http://www.fnal.gov/docs/working-groups/fpcltf/Pkg/ISOcxx/doc/POD.html for more details. And as Armen notes, you can declare POD types as either class or struct without any performance difference; it is simply style.

Comment: The pedant would note that `class` could also be used instead of `typename` to declare a template parameter, while `struct` cannot. But that's just a syntactical nitpick without true relevance to the question. `:)` Good answer, `+1` from me.

Comment: @sbi: The funny thing is that I did consider writing about that syntactic "difference" too, but thought it would be overly pedantic... You never know what reaction it would cause :))

Comment: @Armen: Of course, had _you_ listed this yourself, I'd have quickly pointed out that it is _totally irrelevant_ for the question at hand and had best been left out of your answer. `:)`

Comment: @sbi: I am absolutely sure you would do exactly that :)))

Comment: Damn. Am I really _that_ predictable? `:(`

Comment: @sbi: when it comes to pedantry? Most C++ people are. ;)

Answer (score 15):

1) There is no real difference between the 2 other than the fact that struct members are, by default, public where classes are private.

2) No its EXACTLY the same.

Edit:  Bear in mind you can use virtual inheritance with structs.  They are THAT identical :)

Comment: You can even declare a class with the class keyword and define it using struct, and vice versa :)

Comment: @Armen:  It warns you against doing it though.  Always make sure you have 0 warnings! ;)

Comment: Naturally, I just wanted to emphasize your point that they are THAT identical

Answer (score 9):

Instead of cheaping out and referring to other questions, I'll re-iterate what others have said before I add on to them.

`struct` and `class` are identical in C++, the only exception being that `struct` has a default access of `public`, and `class` has a default access of private.  Performance and language feature support are identical.

Idiomatically, though, `struct` is mostly used for "dumb" classes (plain-old-data).  `class` is used more to embody a true class.

In addition, I've also used `struct` for locally defined function objects, such as:

```
struct something
{
    something() : count(0) { }
    void operator()(int value) { std::cout << value << "-" << count++ << "\n"; }
    int count;
} doSomething;

std::vector<int> values;

...

std::foreach(values.begin(); values.end(); doSomething);
```

Comment: Love the example as it is something that I have yet to encounter in any elementary c++ class (educational =D no pun intended).

Comment: @g19fanatic: They're probably waiting for lambdas.  Or going "locally defined function - why would I want *that* /SticksTongueOut"?

Answer (score 1):

as others have explained, they're the same thing except for default access levels.

the only reason why classes can be perceived to be slower is because a good style (but not the only one) is the one mentioned by [ArmenTsirunyan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090794/c-when-should-i-use-structs-instead-of-classes-and-where-are-the-speed-differe/4090818#4090818): `struct` for POD types, `class` for full-fledged object classes. The latter ones usually include inheritance and virtual methods, hence vtables, which **are** slightly slower to call than straight functions.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use classes when I need to have an explicit destructor. Because then, you should be following the rule of three, in which case you need to write a copy constructer and assignment overloader. With all of this, it seems more natural to use a class than a struct.